# question appearing simultaneously in Stackoverflow and Cross validated

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, duplicate-questions

Is there a way to close the question or mark it as duplicate in Stackoverflow that already appeared on Cross Validated or vice versa?

Comment: What question is it?

Comment: For example: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125368/generate-random-sample-in-r/16125468?noredirect=1#comment23033459_16125468) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56700/random-sample-using-kde-or-bootstrapping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to mark as a duplicate from another site. However, you can flag a diamond moderator. Pick `other`, and in the reason, provide the link to the duplicate question.